# Cucumber scenario interruption by condition

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I am a newbie to cucumber and I haven't found yet a way to interrupt cucumber scenario by condition. I'm trying to implement some scenario:

```
Scenario: Check some value
  When get some value if it's present
  Then parse this value
  And check value #1
  And check value #2
  And check value #3...
```

I have several steps for several value checking and I want to skip all of the checks if value is empty, but I don't want the scenario to be failure in that case. Can anybody please give an advise of implementing that case?

Comment: throw new AssumptionViolatedException("Value is empty") will skip the rest of steps

Comment: @Grasshopper, and is there any way to have such a scenario finished successfully (not skipped)?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to write a scenario like this. As you are in your test environment you have control over whether the value is present or not. The presence/absence of that value is indicative of some previous behaviour. So you have two scenarios

```
Scenario: Something has happened and the value is present
Scenario: Something has NOT happened the the value is absent
```

In the first scenario you can do you extra checks and if things pass you know things are OK. In the second scenario you know you don't need to do your extra checks so you can do something else instead.

You never want to have scenarios pass when they should be failing. If you need some sort of IF statement in your scenario you need refactor and extract additional scenarios.

Comment: The point is that I have to check some external value, I have no control over it. If this value is empty, it's ok and scenario result should be successful, but if it's not empty, I need to do some extra checks to understand, should be the result successful or not. Unfortunately, I have too little experience in Cucumber, so for me it's not obvious how can I split this scenario in two

Comment: So you are using Cucumber to test a live site that you have no control over? If thats the case you probably want to refine the question, and perhaps give a more concrete example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: In complete agreement with @diabolist - this is not how you should be using Cucumber. Please refer to the [Cucumber FAQ](https://docs.cucumber.io/community/faq/#how-can-i-make-cucumber-conditionally-skip-steps)